# Is there one reference for all the abbreviations used here?

Tags: discussion, english, writing-style

My native language is not English, and I've seen many shortcuts of words used by a lot of users here, such as these words:

- OP: Original Poster
- SO: Stack Overflow
- AFAIK: As far as I know ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=en&text=AFAIK))

etc..

These abbreviations are very important for me, to reduce words and improve the sentence.

So, I have one question and one suggestion

**Where can I find a list of these abbreviations, to reduce the attempts to search for it each time?**

The suggestion is:

**Is not it a good idea to group these words and abbreviations in one place, for example, in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).?**

So to speak, to make it as a reference for new users or whose native language is not the English language.

Comment: OP = Original Poster.

Comment: @yivi OP isn't really "native" - it's adopted, since it existed in forums for way, way longer than SO. OP = "original poster", the person who started a given thread. It's also widely used in non-"traditional" (as in old-style) forums like image boards and Reddit. It's being applied here because it's very applicable. TC is *usually* equivalent but not in the SO context, since it stands for "thread creator".

Comment: Funny thing is that MSE is called meta.stackexchange.com, but also math.stackexchange.com :-) It is context-dependent.

Comment: @peterh Usually math.stackexchange.com is Math.SE

Comment: @JL2210 On the MSE, but not on the math meta :-)

Comment: @peterh Math.MSE?

Comment: FYI, "OP" changes based on context. It can mean "original poster" or "original post." Note that this does *not* always refer to the author of a question; it can also refer to the author of an answer. Personally, I just avoid that one since it's used so many different ways.

Comment: _"abbreviations are very important for me, to reduce words and improve the sentence."_ Note that abbreviations rarely improve sentences, they simply shorten them. As you have discovered yourself, abbreviations can be confusing. Don't use them unless necessary.

Comment: The best thing about OP is that it is gender neutral - you can just use it without having to do any of the usual dance around guessing how to refer to someone.

Comment: Another one - CV (close vote) or VTC (vote to close).

Comment: Note that the site [`https://acronymfinder.com/`](https://acronymfinder.com/) is a rather useful resource for acronyms in general, not just those found on SO.  It handles all three of the examples given in the question — though Stack Overflow is not at the top of the list (but it is a 5-star match, along with a lot of other meanings).  I have no association with the site; I'm just a long-time satisfied user.

Comment: Annoyingly the ABBR HTML tag is not supported.

Comment: The best abbrevation is obviously IANAL. Seldom used on SO, but widely used on various other SE sites...

Comment: @AnasAlweish FYI doesn't really belong in the list.  FYI is exceptionally common beyond SO and there isn't a site specific definition - frankly I see it used much more outside of SO and in every day life (at least in the English speaking world)

Comment: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/997587)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Many of the abbreviations you mention are not Stack Overflow specific, but are commonly used on forums or other places on the internet, or are common text-speak.  Often you can find the answers simply by googling the abbreviation.  Another resource are websites like https://acronymfinder.com/ as mentioned by [Jonathan Leffler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in the comments can help as well

For many of the SO specific terms, what you are looking for is here: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

If it isn't there, then it is either non-standard or so common on the internet that it isn't necessary to include it in that Q&A.  Putting it directly in the help center is not a good idea because it is harder to edit.  As a MSE Question and Answer, it becomes very easy for the community to edit and maintain.